# How to check which form is submited in PHP

Tags: php, html, post, form-submit, registration

I have a problem with a Registration/LogIn form submission.
I have two forms in my main php as follows:

```
<form role="form" action="profile.php" onsubmit="return validateForm1()" method="post" class="login-form" name="form1" id="form1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn1" name="btn1">Sign in!</button>
</form>
```

and

```
<form role="form" action="profile.php" onsubmit="return validateForm2()" method="post" class="registration-form" name="form2" id="form2">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-first-name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="Username..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-username-2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-last-name">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Email..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="form-email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="form-email" placeholder="Password..." class="form-email form-control" id="form-password-2">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-about-yourself">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="form-confirm-pass" placeholder="Confirm Password..." class="form-email form-control" id="form-password-3">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" name="btn2" id="btn2">Sign me up!</button>
</form>
```

Then I have the profile.php as follows:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btn2'])) {

$usr = $_POST['form-username-2'];
$pass = $_POST['form-password-2'];
$email = $_POST['form-email'];

echo $usr;
echo $pass;
echo $email;

}

?>
```

As far as I tried I can't get the values echoed right on the other side, there is nothing printed
I'm trying to get the values only if I press the register button.
I tried the SERVER option but it works with both buttons, but I want it to work with the second.
Could you please help me out with this?
Thank you very much (sorry if my English is not good in advance...)

EDIT:
I provide you the Javascript code as I figured out without it it works... Please tell me whats wrong with the javascript validations...

```
<script>
    function validateForm1()
    {
        var name = document.forms["form1"]["form-username"].value;
        var pass = document.forms["form1"]["form-password"].value;
        var format = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;

        if (pass.length < 7){
            alert("Please enter at least 7 character password");
            return false;
        }
        if (!format.test(pass)){
            alert("Please enter at a symbol in password");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
</script>

<script>
    function validateForm2()
    {
        var name = document.forms["form2"]["form-username-2"].value;
        var mail = document.forms["form2"]["form-last-name"].value;
        var pass1 = document.forms["form2"]["form-password-2"].value;
        var pass2 = document.forms["form2"]["form-password-3"].value;

        var passformat = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
        var mailformat = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

        if (pass1 != pass2){
            alert("Confirmation password doesn't match");
            return false;
            }
        if (pass1.length < 7){
            alert("Please enter at least 7 character password");
            return false;
        }
        if (!passformat.test(pass1)){
            alert("Please enter at a symbol in password");
            return false;
        }
        if (!mailformat.test(mail)){
            alert("Please enter a valid email");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` is your friend.

Comment: @himal and use it how please?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. If you want to handle the submission of the registration form, check for the existence of `$_POST['btn2']`. If you want to handle login, it's `$_POST['btn1']`.

Comment: @UtKanos isn't that what I do with isset? when I fill the form I still get nothing on the other side... but when I don't check isset I get the values correctly, but when I press btn1 there are errors cause vars are empty

Comment: Show us the Javascript code for `validateForm1` and `validateForm2`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I added it at the initial code. The problem seems to be the js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just need to add double test :

```
if (isset($_POST['btn1'])) {

...

} elseif(isset($_POST['btn2'])) {

...

}
```

Try this :

```js
$.validate({
    lang: 'en',
    modules : 'security'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.3.26/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<form role="form" action="profile.php"  method="post" class="login-form" name="form1" id="form1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label>
            <input data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password">Password</label>
            <input data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min8" type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password">
        </div>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn" id="btn1" name="btn1">Sign in!</button>
    </form>
    
    <form role="form" action="profile.php"  method="post" class="registration-form" name="form2" id="form2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-username-2">Username</label>
            <input data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min4" type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Username..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username-2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
            <input data-validation="email"  type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Email..." class="form-email form-control" id="form-email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-password-2">Password</label>
            <input data-validation="confirmation length" data-validation-length="min8" type="password" name="form-password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-password-2">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="form-confirm-pass">Confirm Password</label>
            <input  type="password" name="form-password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="form-confirm-pass">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="btn2" id="btn2">Sign me up!</button>
    </form>
```

profile.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['btn1'])) {

    $username = $_POST['form-username'];
    $password = $_POST['form-password'];

    echo $username;
    echo $password;

} elseif(isset($_POST['btn2'])) {

    $username = $_POST['form-username'];
    $email = $_POST['form-email'];
    $password = $_POST['form-password'];

    echo $username;
    echo $email;
    echo $password;

}

?>
```

Comment: still get nothing... I put echo "btn1" on the first end echo "btn2" on the second. profile.php is blank

Comment: in your second form set the input **username name** and the input **email name**

Comment: Check your JavaScript validation or remove 
 `onsubmit="return validateForm1()"` also remove `onsubmit="return validateForm2()"`

Comment: @STRATOSpeed i edited you code in my answer check it, hope it  will help !!

Comment: @KrDjamel Thanks mate your code is fine, the problem seems to be the javascripts though...

Comment: @STRATOSpeed , i replace your **js form validator hardcoded**  with this library [form validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/) it's easy to use , i add a snippet of that check it .

Comment: I did some adjustments too and it works fine now! there were some problems with onsubmit and  action together, had to go with the names of vars and some other small changes. but the your implementation is great! thank you for your time! cheers

Answer (score 1):

$_POST will not contain the "submit" button value "bt1" when you submit the 2nd form, and vice-versa.
Best practice is to use a hidden field instead to determine what form you are in. For instance, use this inside the 1st form: `<input type="hidden" name="which_form" value="form1"/>`
and then `<input type="hidden" name="which_form" value="form2"/>` inside the 2nd form.
Then you can check the value of $_POST['which_form'] to determine what form was posted.

Comment: Really? Why wont it?

Comment: @Yoshimitsu I see what you trying to do there, but still I have problem. For instance, in the first form submission, when I echo $_POST['form-username'] I see the username, but when I echo  $_POST['which_form'] I get undefined index error...

Comment: @yoshimitsu please review your answer as it's not entirely accurate.

Comment: @BobbyAxe if it is, I can't spot it. What is it?

Comment: `$_POST will not contain the "submit" button value` This may not be true

Comment: @STRATOSpeed please check your typing, as I know for sure that this definitely works.